# Collaborative website for a small research lab

Tags: gratis, collaboration, wiki, moinmoin

I currently have a wiki website for my research lab. This website is based on [MoinMoin](http://moinmo.in/) 1.9.x. Even though I find it very convenient (especially since it is open source) I am looking for a more efficient solution.

In particular, I would like a more efficient way to share documents and potentially allow for web meetings. But I would also like to keep the user friendly approach of a wiki website, specifically for page edition.

I have mostly investigated for other types of wiki websites ([mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki), [foswiki](https://foswiki.org/)...) but I could not find what I am looking for.

I would rather avoid commercial solutions or solutions that depend on a remote server (for confidentiality issue).

Would you have any suggestions?

**Update:** I realize it is difficult to generate comments or discussion on this topic. It is likely I am missing the proper keywords to accurately describe the kind of tool I am looking for. So, in order to try to make things clearer, here are the functionalities I use with my MoinMoin wiki as well as a list of options I would like to add:

**MoinMoin's functionalities**:

1. **page edition**:

   - it is easy and allows each student to create his own research journal
   - it embeds version control which is very practical
   - it is easy to add documents and attachments
   - **as a downside**:

     1. it is impossible to add more than one attachment at a time which makes file upload somehow time consuming (drag and drop would be great, **Moodle** websites typically feature this),
     2. parsers such as the LaTeX parser are consuming in terms of CPU resources and slow down page browsing and edition,
     3. there is no built-in modules for table editions or spreadsheets which would be most practical for planning research tasks.
2. **ACL permissions**:

   - really a nice feature of MoinMoin as it is easy to provide access to a list of members to a given page,
   - hierarchical permissions are also great: students do not need to worry for permissions as long as they create subpages,
   - **as a downside**:

     1. it is not possible to know, on a given subpage, who has access to it,
     2. it seems that allowing a user to manage ACL permissions is basically giving him access to the whole website: a user cannot manage ACL on his own page only.